# Why method overloading is not allowed in WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, overloading

Assume that this is a `ServiceContract`

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface MyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    int Sum(int x, int y);

    [OperationContract]
    int Sum(double x, double y);

}
```

Method overloading is allowed in C#, but WCF does not allow you to overload `operation contracts`
The hosting program will throw an `InvalidOperationException` while hosting

Comment: I'm not sure this is the _correct_ answer so I'll post as a comment.  I believe it is because WCF is designed to work with as many protocols as possible, i.e. non-Microsoft technologies too.  Overloading is a feature to .Net and a few other languages, but not all.  To maximise the availability of services, overloading isn't allowed.  (I think)

Comment: Seems like a good answer to me.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

In a nutshell, the reason you cannot overload methods has to do with the fact that WSDL does not support the same overloading concepts present inside of C#. The following post provides details on why this is not possible.

http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2006/09/21/Overloading-Methods-in-WCF.aspx

To work around the issue, you can explicitly specify the `Name` property of the `OperationContract`.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface MyService
{
    [OperationContract(Name="SumUsingInt")]
    int Sum(int x, int y);

    [OperationContract(Name="SumUsingDouble")]
    int Sum(double x, double y);
}
```

Answer (score 28):

Because when invoking over HTTP/SOAP, having **the same method name in your contract** would mean that there's no way to determine which particular method the client is about to invoke.

Remember that when invoking web methods over http, arguments are optional and are initialized with default values if missing. This means that invocation of both methods could look exactly the same way over HTTP/SOAP.

Answer (score 1):

The reason being that WCF is supposed to be universally usable by different clients and those clients do not have to be .NET and may also not allow `Operator/Method overloading` in their frameworks. If that is the case, then this method becomes unusable by those frameworks and therefore to ensure it is universally usable, WCF disallows and provides you with a name property in the `OperationContract` attribute to specify a different name. If the client is a .NET, then WCF will automatically show it as a method overload but otherwise it will generate a new method with the name specified in the name property.