# How can i have two methods with same name in WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [why you cant overload a method in WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276124/why-you-cant-overload-a-method-in-wcf)

I am working on one project in which I use the WCF services. My problem is that in WCF service I am having one method named `Display()` which is used by me client1.

Now I want to add another method with the same name but with one parameter, ie. `Display(string name)`, so that new clinet2 can use the new method and old client1 can use the old method. how can I achieve this? Here is the code which I have written.

```
namespace ContractVersioningService
{
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IService1 
  {
    [OperationContract]
    string Display();

    [OperationContract]
    string GoodNight();
  }     
}

namespace ContractVersioningService
{
   public class Service1 : IService1
   {
     public string Display()
     {
        return "Good Morning";          
     }

     public string GoodNight()
     {
        return "Good Night";
     }
   }
}    

namespace ContractVersioningService
{
  [ServiceContract(Namespace = "ContractVersioningService/01", Name =      "ServiceVersioning")]
  public interface IService2 : IService1
  {
     [OperationContract]
     string Disp(string greet);
  }
}

namespace ContractVersioningService
{
 
   public class Service2 : Service1, IService2
   {
      public string Display(string name)
      {
         return name;
      }

      public string Disp(string s)
      {
         return s;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: @Cristian as per your link we need to provide the "name" attribute to the operation contract. but the problem is the client then can access both method using the attribute "name" value. i want client can access these methods by original names.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14473149/922198

Comment: @Sagar The client will see the names of the methods, not as you have named them in your C# interface, but by the name given in the `OperationContract.Name` value. That is the point of it really, the method will _not_ have the same name. And that is the only way it will work out. You simply cannot have more than one service operation by the exact same name - WSDL does not do overload resolution. Hence, this is a duplicate to the linked question.

Comment: @Christian.K but i want that client see only one common name. how can i achieve it?

Comment: WCF does **not support** method overloading, e.g. you **cannot** have two methods of the same name that just have different list of parameters. The names in the service description **must be unique**. There's no way around that requirement.

Comment: @marc_s I already have client who is using one method and now my new client need to user new method with same name but with one parameter. can i achieve this?

Comment: No you **cannot**. **Not** with the same method name.

Comment: Maybe it's a solution for you that you create a Facade for your client? So that your client doesn't call the Service himself, but uses your Facade which calls the Service. This way your Facade can use method overloading, while internally calling differently named methods of the service.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
    Why WCF doesnot support method overloading directly ?
```

- Because WSDL doesnot support method overloading(not OOPs).
  WCF generates WSDL which specifies the location of the service and the operation or methods the service exposes.

  **WCF use Document/Literal WSDL Style** : Microsoft proposed this standard where the soap body element will contain the web method name.
- By default all the WCF services conform to the document literal standard where the soap body should include the method name.

  The only way is using Name attribute. For eg,

  ```
      [OperationContract(Name="Integers")]
      int Display(int a,int b)
      [OperationContract(Name="Doubles")]
      double Display(double a,double b)
  ```

The the compiler will generate the following, which makes sense for wsdl to locate

```
     [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName=
    "ServiceRef.IService1")]
  public interface IService1
   {
       [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(
       Action="http://tempuri.org/Service1/AddNumber",
       ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IHelloWorld/IntegersResponse")]                   
       int Display(int a,int b)

       [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(
       Action="http://tempuri.org/IHelloWorld/ConcatenateStrings",
       ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/Service1/DoublesResponse")]
       double Display(double a,double b)
  }
```

Comment: Here then calling method will be using the "Ingeters()" and "Doubles()". I want to user method by there original name( i.e, Display)

Comment: Method overloading in a single servicecontract without name attribute is not possible. But you can expose it as two different contracts.

Comment: Can call by original (display) name by using Name attribute. I think you update the name attribute on server side only. It has to be on both sides.

Comment: Is it possible to change the the clients reference.cs file from server side?

Comment: No.How you create your proxy (serviceutil/Channelfactory)? You can get alias name only on client side, if you implement name property in server side only.. so update on both sides, u get the original name.. This may help http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_wcf/article.php/c14773/How-to-Achieve-Operational-Overloading-in-WCF.htm

Comment: This i have already implemented. But suppose my wcf service is to be user be 3rd party client whose reference.cs file is not accessible then it is not possible. any suggestion on this?

Comment: If you are on server side ,the consumer(client) contract depends on server. The server used to give the clientbase and contract signature to client(eventhough it is unknown). Simple, Server side and client side contract signatures should match at any cost.

Answer (score 7):

OK, I'm going to make this an answer, since the comments get overly excessive by now.

You basically have two options:

- Use a single interface (note that interface inheritance, like you suggest in your question, technically counts as *one* interface here), but then you *have to* give each service operation a distinct name. You can either do that by naming the C# methods distinct, or by applying the `[OperationContract(Name = "distinctname")]` attribute.
- Use two separate interfaces, without any inheritance relationship in between them, publishing each on a different endpoint. You can have then have a service operation in each, having the same name, but with different parameters. You can still implement both interfaces with one implementation class, if you like/need to, of course.

Comment: But i have to explicitly implement all the method from both interfaces.

Comment: Yes, but is that an issue? You would have to do that anyway.

Comment: yes it is.... it will unnecessarily increase the code.

Comment: Then delegate. One function (the old one) could call the new one, providing a sensible default value for the new/extra parameter. Other than that, I'm afraid, I cannot see your problem here. It looks like a regular/usual thing to do - with or without WCF. You should probably consider posting a new question or update the current one with more details.